# The file application.hbs is the main template in ember js?

Tags: ember.js

I don't understand how it works !? The template application.hbs appear first on every page that I create.

The container has a div#ember365 how is created and were?

Comment: The application template is the default template that is rendered when your application starts.https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/the-application-template/

Answer (score 0):

The `application.hbs` is the template rendered and contains a `{{yield}}` tag.  Ember is a Single Page Application (SPA) so the template doesnt reload on clicks.  Instead whats inside dynamically changes similar like you would see in jquery partial page updates.  Everything is rendered in that template.  You should be nesting in that components or other routes.  Other routes will appear in your `{{yield}}` tag.

docs: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/handlebars-basics/

in the docs, make sure youre looking at the same version as the version of ember youre working with.